# Is there any way I can restrict Chrome from taking up so much memory?

Tags: google-chrome, memory

What does Chrome do that takes so much memory?
I have three tabs open only.

- This page of course
- an article on gameskinny.com
- one tab with Google search

  None of the last two are more demanding than superuser.com but still it's using  1 GB of RAM.

Is the memory usage really necessary or is there any way I can restrict it and still use Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web browser memory usage](https://superuser.com/questions/159596/web-browser-memory-usage)

Comment: I've edited your question, since I think the last part of your post is what you really want to know. "How does Chrome use the ram" seems like something that could get very technical and not really help you reduce your chrome memory issue.

Comment: Duplicate of [Limiting use of RAM in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/413349/limiting-use-of-ram-in-chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the extension like [TabSuspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-suspender/fiabciakcmgepblmdkmemdbbkilneeeh) which will reduce the memory usage by Chrome **upto 80%**

From the extension's doc:

> Automatically **suspend, park, hibernate inactive tabs** and save up to
>   80% of memory, reduce load on your device, battery and heat.

I have **56 tabs open** in my chrome at this moment, which consumes around **2 GB only** as per Chrome's task manager.